# windows 8 app: what the meaning of parentedComplete()?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro

In the default VS templates for developing win8 app, there is a function: parentedComplete(), such as,

```
    args.detail.setPromise(
    WinJS.Promise.timeout().then(function () {
        if (that.pageElement.winControl && that.pageElement.winControl.unload) {
            that.pageElement.winControl.unload();
        }
        return WinJS.UI.Pages.render(args.detail.location, newElement, args.detail.state, parented);
    }).then(function parentElement(control) {
        that._previousPage = newElement.winControl;
        that.element.appendChild(newElement);
        that.element.removeChild(that.pageElement);

        **parentedComplete();**
```

I can't find any documents about this built-in function, could anyone explain this function to me.